# Proving this set is an algebra.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning

Let $J = \{$all intervals contained in $[0,1]\}$  and $B_0 = \{$all finite unions of elements of $J\}$.

Prove that $B_o$ contains $[0,1], \emptyset$, and is closed under formation of complements and of finite unions and intersections, i.e., prove that $B_0$ is an algebra.

How do I prove that $B_0$ is closed under complements?

Comment: Finite intersections and unions of intervals are finite unions of intervals. Prove that first. Then complement of an interval is a union of (two) intervals. Finally complement of finite union of intervals is an intersection of the complments of the interval joined.

Comment: They must be considering all intervals $(a,b), [a,b), (a,b], [a,b]$.

Comment: Figure out what those complements look like.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for letting me work through this. Below are my attempts at proofs, corrections are ,as always, warmly welcome.

Finite intersection of intervals are finite unions of intervals Proof:

An interval is a set of real numbers with the property that any number that lies between two numbers in the set is also included in the set.

Take any two intervals $A = [i_1, i_2]$ and $B=[i_3,i_4]$ where $i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4 \in R$.

$$A \cap B = \{x \in R : i_1\le x \le i_2 \text{ and } i_3 \le x \le i_4 \}$$

1. In the case $i_2 < i_3 \ A \cap B = \emptyset = \emptyset \cup \emptyset $
2. In the case $i_3 < i_2 < i_4  \ A \cap B = \{x \in R : i_3\le x \le i_2 \}$
3. ...

We can see that in all the cases we obtain a single interval and because $A \cap B \cap C  = (A \cap B) \cap C$, where $C$ is an other interval $\in R$ we can extend this to any finite intersection.

Complement of an interval is a union of two intervals Proof:

Take any interval $A = [i_1, i_2]$ and $i_1,i_2 \in R$.

$$R \backslash A = \{ x \in R : x \notin A\}=\{x \in R : x < i_1 \text{ or } x > i_2 \} = (- \infty, i_1) \cup (i_2, +\infty)   $$

Then by Demorgans law the result I was trying to prove follows.

Comment: This is not quite right. You need to prove that $B_0$ is closed under finite intersection, finite union, and complement. Right now, you proved that applying these operations to $J$ yields elements of $B_0$. That's an important starting point to see how the general case works, but you still have some work to do.